# How do I put an array in a textarea, putting each element on its own line?

Tags: javascript, arrays, textarea

How do I output array elements in a textarea, placing each element on its own line?

```js
var your_array = [ "Alice", "Bob", "Eve" ];
```

```html
<textarea id="your_textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: Output them with a line break `\n` inbetween.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

An array has a method to glue all elements together, `Array.join`. Without an argument, it would use a comma (`,`) as glue. To put every element on a new line, use the newline character (`\n`).

```js
var your_array = [ "Alice", "Bob", "Eve" ];
var textarea = document.getElementById("your_textarea");
textarea.value = your_array.join("\n");
```

```html
<textarea id="your_textarea"></textarea>
```

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NgSLm/)

Comment: What about if I want to show this >> [ "Alice", "Bob", "Eve" ]  in your_textarea?

Comment: @AnilYadav Try `textarea.value = JSON.stringify(your_array);`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 1):

try to use this

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var msg = a.join("\n");
var area = document.getElementById("textArea");
area.value= msg;
```